# Find non-empty paragraphs in Word with VBA

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, vbscript

I'm writing a script in VBScript that scans through a collection of 2000 Word files and looks for those that contain at least a paragraph using an unwanted style. So, the core of my script is:

```
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(objFile.Path)

With objDoc.Range.Find
.Style = objDoc.Styles("Unwanted")

SearchSuccessful = .Execute

If SearchSuccessful Then
    foundStyle = True
End If
End With
```

Now, my problem is that I'm only interested in non-empty paragraph. Is there a way I can use the Find property to search for a non-empty paragraph? Or do I need to loop and test for the found paragraph length?

Thanks!

Comment: VBA is not VBScript. Which are you using?

Comment: Specifically VBScript, but I'm using objects defined in Word VBA.